# mysql complex request by distinct pair (non commutative)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to create an sql (mariadb) request that select multiples columns but need two columns to be a unique pair but making sure the pair selected has its created_at value the least than the other duplicata pairs.

Here is what my table approximately looks like :

| id | from_user_id | to_user_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1000000005 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1000000002 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 1000000008 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 999999999 |
| 5 | 6 | 5 | 100000006 |

I made this table precise to explain the request I want.

So I want to select the distinct pair (from_user_id, to_user_id) implying that the couple (1,2) which could also be (2,1) should be unique. The second rule is it should pick the couple with the minimum created_at value.

So the result table I want is :

| id | from_user_id | to_user_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1000000002 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 1000000008 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 999999999 |

2,1,1000000002 because the created_at is lesser than the other same couple case (1,2,1000000005).

In this case if I want only the values above created_at:999999999 to be selected I just have to add one condition.

I really hope my question is clear. I'm struggling to make distinct pairs work with other columns.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH
cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GREATEST(from_user_id,to_user_id), 
                                              LEAST(from_user_id,to_user_id) 
                                 ORDER BY created_at) rn
    FROM table
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```